# Insert a waypoint into a POSTGIS table with psycopg2 and ST_GeographyFromText

Tags: python, postgis, python-3, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a waypoint into a table with 1 foreign key refererance and a geography point in PostGIS. I am having no luck.

The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE route
                (id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                route_name varchar);

CREATE TABLE planned_waypoints
                (id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                route_id serial REFERENCES route(id),
                timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
                planned_waypoint geography(Point, 4326));
```

First to insert the route I use

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO route (route_name) VALUES (%s)  RETURNING id;', (r_name,))
r_name_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

to insert the waypoint, I have tried

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints (route_id, planned_waypoint) VALUES (%s, ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(%s %s)) );""", (r_name_id, lat, long, )
```

However this returns an error message.

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "11.197973099081285"
LINE 1: ...(62, ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(48.07093992348414 11.1979730...
```

I have tried various approaches, including using Python string formatting (it failed), using a dictionary for the variables and so forth. None of these approaches have yielded a successful insert.

For example:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints (route_id, planned_waypoint) VALUES (%s, %s ) ;""", (r_name_id, ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(lat long)), ))
```

which produces:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints (route_id, planned_waypoint) VALUES (%s, %s ) ;""", (r_name_id, ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(lat long)), ))
                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm pretty new to sql and psycopg2.

results of

and

```
print(cur.mogrify("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints (route_id, planned_waypoint) VALUES (%s, %s ) ;""",r_name_id, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(lat long)'),  ).decode())
```

produces:

```
NameError: name 'ST_GeographyFromText' is not defined 



print(cur.mogrify("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints (route_id, planned_waypoint) VALUES (%s, %s ) ;""",r_name_id, ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(lat long)),  ).decode())
                                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with a cursor pointing to long

Solution, as proposed by @swiss_knight’s answer,

```
from psycopg2 import sql
    sql_qry = sql.SQL("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints
    (route_id, planned_waypoint)
    VALUES ({}, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT({} {})')));"""
).format(
    sql.Literal(r_name_id),
    sql.Literal(lat),
    sql.Literal(long)
)
    print(sql_qry.as_string(conn))
```

produces:

```
INSERT INTO planned_waypoints
    (route_id, planned_waypoint)
    VALUES (111, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(48.07059854740867 11.198530422437894)'));
```

Which looks like it should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your Point into single quotes:

```
SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(48.07093 11.19797)')
```

->
[image]

vs

```
SELECT ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(48.07093 11.19797))

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "11.19797"
LINE 1: SELECT ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(48.07093 11.19797))
                                                   ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 44
```

In addition, you cannot do it this way:

```
print(cur.mogrify(
    """INSERT INTO planned_waypoints
    (route_id, planned_waypoint)
    VALUES (%s, %s );
    """,
    r_name_id,
    ST_GeographyFromText(POINT(lat long))
).decode())
```

Try it like that:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
sql_qry = sql.SQL("""INSERT INTO planned_waypoints
    (route_id, planned_waypoint)
    VALUES ({}, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT({} {})')));"""
).format(
    sql.Literal(r_name_id),
    sql.Literal(lat),
    sql.Literal(long)
)
print(sql_qry.as_string(conn))
```

Which should print a valid SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO planned_waypoints (route_id, planned_waypoint)
VALUES (1, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(48.7777 11.22222)')));
```

See: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html